# Is there a more concise way of writing repetitive code changing which method is used?

Tags: java, loops, methods

I've written a very repetitive piece of code (as seen below) and I feel that there has to be some way to use a method to make it more concise, but I cannot figure out how.

This is the current code snippet:

```java
if (event.getSource() == firstNameButton) {
    inputType = "first name";
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        if (myList[i].getFirstName().equals(input)) {
            returnList[returnLength] = myList[i];
            returnLength++;
        }
    }
} else if (event.getSource() == lastNameButton) {
    inputType = "last name";
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        if (myList[i].getLastName().equals(input)) {
            returnList[returnLength] = myList[i];
            returnLength++;
        }
    }
} else if (event.getSource() == usernameButton) {
    inputType = "username";
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        if (myList[i].getUsername().equals(input)) {
            returnList[returnLength] = myList[i];
            returnLength++;
        }
    }
} else if (event.getSource() == domainNameButton) {
    inputType = "domain name";
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        if (myList[i].getDomainName().equals(input)) {
            returnList[returnLength] = myList[i];
            returnLength++;
        }
    }
} else if (event.getSource() == domainExtensionButton) {
    inputType = "domain extension";
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        if (myList[i].getDomainExtension().equals(input)) {
            returnList[returnLength] = myList[i];
            returnLength++;
        }
    }
}
```

The only things changing are what `inputType` gets assigned to, which I would be able to write a method for, but I am also changing what method I apply to `myList[i]`. Is there a way to write a method with a method parameter?

Comment: read up on java lambda expressions

Comment: @OldProgrammer Could you show me an example? I see that it is probably what I need but I don't quite understand.

Comment: Indeed. You can use `Function<WhatEverTypeIsInMyList, String>` as declaration, and `WhatEverTypeIsInMyList::getFirstName`, `WhatEverTypeIsInMyList::getLastName`, etc. as values. To compare the value, just use `myFunc.apply(myList[i]).equals(input)`.

Comment: A good start is using good names: `myList` is obviously not in fact a `List` but an *array*, but regardless should typically be named as the plural of the type of objects holds, which you haven't told us. Please tell us the type returned from `event.getSource()`, the array type of `myList` and the reason you are using arrays instead of Lists.

Comment: And once you created your unified method, I'd suggest you create a separate `ActionListener` per button so you don't have to query the event source initially.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that `myList` is an array of class `MyList`.
Add the following method to class `MyList`.

```java
public class MyList {
    public String getValue(String key) {
        return switch (key) {
                   case "first name" -> getFirstName();
                   case "last name" -> getLastName();
                   case "username" -> getUsername();
                   case "domain name" -> getDomainName();
                   case "domain extension" -> getDomainExtension();
               }
    }
}
```

The above method uses [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) which were added in Java 12.

Assume the code in your question is from an [actionPerformed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) method.
Assume that `firstNameButton`, `lastNameButton`, etc, are all [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)s.
Then you can assign an appropriate *action command* to each, for example:

```java
firstNameButton.setActionCommand("first name");
```

Now your `actionPerformed` method can be reduced to:

```java
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
    String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        if (myList[i].getValue(actionCommand).equals(input)) {
            returnList[returnLength] = myList[i];
            returnLength++;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html):

```java
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
    String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
    java.util.Arrays.stream(myList)
                    .filter(m -> m.getValue(actionCommand).equals(input))
                    .findFirst()
                    .ifPresent(m -> {
                                   returnList[returnLength] = myList[i];
                                   returnLength++;
                               });
}
```

Note that method `findFirst` returns an object of type [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstraction for extracting data from your object. You need something which accepts argument of type your custom class and return string result, [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) will do, but you can create your own as well. Extract the repetition to a method, using the abstraction:

```
private void myMethod(MyObject[] myList, Function<MyObject, String> valueExtractor, String input) {
  for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    if (valueExtractor.apply(myList[i]).equals(input)) {
      //do required stuff
    }
  }
}
```

You can still use `if-else` to get the correct extractor, but i would suggest to use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead to keep the keys and their respective extraction functions:

```
Map<String, Function<MyObject, String>> map = Map.of("firstNameButton", MyObject::getFirstName, 
  "lastNameButton", MyObject::getLastName);
Function<MyObject, String> extractor = map.get(event.getSource());
myMethod(theList, extractor, theInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an "Old Dog" approach:

Repeated or nearly repeated sections of code can be often be reduced with arrays and / or `Collection` Objects, loops, and methods. What parts of the nearly repeated code are the same, and what parts are different?

```
  if (event.getSource() == *********Button) {
      inputType = "**********";
      for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
          if (myList[i].get*********().equals(input)) {
              returnList[returnLength] = myList[i];
              returnLength++;
    }
}
```

I replaced the parts of the O/P code that vary with `*********`.

I have to make some assumptions here.

The array `myList` is apparently an array of some sort of `Object`, with various `get`er methods that return some sort of `Object`, probably a `String`. But, I'll use `Bar` in this example:

Suppose `myList` is an array of `Foo`. The beginning of the code for `Foo` might look something like this:

```
 public class Foo { 
    private Bar firstName, lastName, userName, domainName, domainExtension;
```

You could add this method:

```
 public Bar getNameAttribute (int attributeKey) { 
   switch (attributeKey) { 

     case 0: 
       return firstName;
       break;
    case 1: 
       return lastName;
       break;
    case 2:
       ...
    default:
       return null;
       break;
   } 
}
```

Now, the various `~Button` variables are reference types. It's reasonable to assume that, once they are created and initialized, the references will not be changed to point to some other button. In fact, use of `event.getSource () ==` implies that is the case. So, let us use an array to reference them, in addition to referencing them using their individual reference names. I'll assume they are Objects of `JButton` type:

```
 JButton [] nameButton = { firstNameButton, lastNameButton, userNameButton
            , domainNameButton, domainExtensionButton };
 String [] eventType = {"first  name", "last name", "user name"
            , "domain name", "domain extension" };
          

  for (int k = 0; k < nameButton.length; k++) { 
     if (event.getSource() == nameButton [k] { 
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) { 
           if (mylList[i].getNameAttribute[k].equals(input)){
              returnList[returnLength] = myList[i];
              returnLength++;
           }
        }
        break;
     }
  }
```

### Notes:

Use of `switch` in the `getNameAttribute` method assumes references to the various names can be changed. For example, `Foo foo1 = new Foo (...); ... foo1.setFirstName (new Bar ("Jones"));` If, after creation and initialization, references to all of the names are fixed, the `getNameAttribute` code can be reduced by using an array of aliases, as was done with the Buttons.